# Magento : How to Add Quantity Box in Custom Option for Simple Product

Tags: magento-1.9, php, attributes, custom-options

I have a attribute "size" which have drop down option in custom option admin panel, and i want to show quantity box for this option, our all products are simple products.

I have tried below link it will not work fully 
http://hkpatel201.blogspot.in/2014/03/how-to-add-custom-qty-to-custom-option.html

**I am trying the below code**

```
  1.go to app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\catalog\product\edit\options\type\select.phtml

  Find the below code:
 '<th class="type-sku"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('SKU') ?></th>'+

  Now add following code just after above code.
 '<th class="type-qty"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Qty') ?></th>'+

  Find the below code:
  '<td><input type="text" class="input-text" name="product[options][{{id}}][values][{{select_id}}][sku]" value="{{sku}}"></td>'+

  Now add following code just after above code.
  '<td><input type="text" class="input-text" name="product[options][{{id}}][values][{{select_id}}][qty]" value="{{qty}}"></td>'+

  2. go to app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tab\Options\Option.php

  Find the below code:
  $value['sku'] = $this->htmlEscape($option->getSku());

  Now add following code just after above code.
  $value['qty'] = $this->htmlEscape($option->getQty());

  Find the below code:
  'sku' => $this->htmlEscape($_value->getSku()),

  Now add following code just after above code.
  'qty' => $this->htmlEscape($_value->getQty()),

  3. Add field in “catalog_product_option_type_value” table in database
  `qty` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Qty',
```

After adding this code the quantity box showing in admin panel in custom option and quantity is also save in database.

But problem is this it will not validate quantity in frontend also in stock .

Comment: Please add more details, on which specific part of the code you are getting error?

Comment: I am not getting error , because i don't have much knowledge about magento coding

Comment: If you are not getting error than what is the issue? Can you add more description?

Comment: please read my question

Comment: I want to show quantity box for custom option for simple products in admin panel

Comment: That I can understand from your question. I am asking which thing you cannot do using the reference link? Can you add quantity box using code? Can you save value for you boxes? You said that its not working fully that means there are some specific parts where you are facing issues.

Comment: ok, i have implement the code using reference link and quantity box added in admin panel and also it's save in database but the main problem is that , its not validate quantity on front end like i have quantity 2 and when we add product in cart with 3 quantity it will add product not show any validation and also not quantity decrease when we purchase that product.

Comment: the main thing is that custom option quantity not work for validation and as well stock

Comment: Please provide the solution if you have ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56715/discussion-between-sheenu-and-jaimin-sutariya).